# Fixed column table with height

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position, bootstrap-4

I have a table where the first three columns should be fixed and rest of the columns should be scroll-able.
[Fiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/Grishma/sgcuvdy2/4/) of the table implementation.

The first columns I made them as fixed by `position:absolute` and having scroll bar to rest of columns with `margin-left`.

```
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col {
    left: 73px;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    width: 230px;
}
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col-2 { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px; left: 35px;
}
.zui-table .zui-sticky-col-1 {
    width: 35px; left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But the issue is, when I have many records, **I need to restrict the height of table by having vertical scrollbar**.

So, I gave `max-height` to `.zui-scroller`, but the fixed columns were out of that height. And another issue is, that the non-fixed column headers are scrolling which should be fixed.

Since this is an existing module which got other functionlity, I cannot use other plugins to achieve this.

Can someone point me the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.zui-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width:30%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Add a fixed height to `zui-wrapper` class with `overflow-y: auto` property. It should work as intended.

https://jsfiddle.net/Grishma/sgcuvdy2/4/

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I was using https://jsfiddle.net/vwt5m214/4/ approach for height Fix. Can you suggest me an approach to make header as fixed while scrolling down(y-axis). Thanks once again!

Comment: Take a look at this example - https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/
I think this is what you want. Just tweak your code according to it.